# Stretch Scale doesn't affect controls generated by code

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Gonna try to be concise & clear once again.

So, making a game, making a game UI for battles, and so I create that UI with code rather than placing it directly in the editor.
And learned to my depend that we don't touch the scale property of each elements to make them scale, rather we use `stretch_scale` and `stretch_mode`.

Problem : While making a ProgressBar, I've seen it was way smaller than the rest, way smaller than intended, like `stretch_scale` doesn't affect it.

(I know this might be a **bug**, a **know one** at that. But I already been fooled this way while learning the existence of `stretch_scale` and `stretch_mode`. Reporting a bug, while it wasn't, and then discovering PopupMenus doesn't scale properly so there was still a bug but still, and so, I'm mostly asking to verify if that really a bug, or an fail on my side)

Hope there wasn't too much rambling, and that I've been concise and clear enough.

Comment: Are you placing the problematic `ProgressBar` in a container? if so, of which kind? - I only find `stretch_mode` refering to texture sizing, or in the `AspectRatioContainer`. I have less idea of the `stretch_scale` you talk about.

Comment: I didn't place the Progress Bar in a container, and your question made me realize that I've already created Control node with code, which worked fine, only difference was they were in a Container, now they're in a Container it works fine. So thanks lol, even if it were by a question.

Comment: And `stretch_scale` is basically an options underneath `stretch_mode` which multiply the size of everything by the said ratio, avoiding to have to resize everything. Throught there bugs with PopupMenu that doesn't scale properly, because they're created afterwards, seems every Control that doesn't have a container have this same bug, gonan report right away, for once that I did catch a real one.

Comment: Isn't that `stretch_mode` you are looking at the one about textures? Edit: That is, this one: [`TextureRect.stretch_mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_texturerect.html#class-texturerect-property-stretch-mode) and this one: [`TextureButton.stretch_mode`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_texturebutton.html#class-texturebutton-property-stretch-mode). They control how the texture is stretched inside of the `Control`, not the size of the `Control` itself. And, of course, only `Control`s with a texture have them. Edit2: still, I think docs could improve.

Comment: What I was talking about the `stretch_mode` and `stretch_scale` were Projects settings, located Display -> Window, section Stretch, not the TextureRect one

Comment: Ah, your controls that are not inside a `Container` are not affected because they would be using anchors and margins instead. See [Size and anchors](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/ui/size_and_anchors.html) *Sadly this documentation is not yet updated :/.*

Comment: Ooow that could explain, since I didn't pay attention to thoses in the first place, especially because I didn't understood how they works, maybe will do when they update the docs lol.
Thanks for all the answers and infos btw.